# Speckle noise from Raspberry Pi NoIR camera V2

Tags: picamera

I'm getting unusual amounts of speckle noise from my RPI camera. Note the black speckles on the image:
[image: noise]
and see a 2 second video showing the same noise [here](https://vision-group-file-sharing.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Data%20backup%20and%20storage/Yakir/a.mp4).

The camera is connected with a 2 meters long ribbon cable (not the default short one you get with the camera), so maybe it's that...? Any idea what's going on...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2-meter ribbon cable can totally be a problem. It's easy to test: if you plug the default cable which came with the camera instead, and the noise goes away, then it's the cable.

The camera was only tested with the cable which is sold with it. Not being able to work with a different cable (especially a 2-meter one) is not really the camera's fault. Those cables are not standard like USB, where every compliant device is supposed to work with every compliant cable.

Not much can be done by the user except for trying a different (preferably shorter) cable.